# What is the exact meaning of the second parameter of the `insnstr` ncurses function?

Tags: unicode, ncurses

`int insnstr(const char *str, int n);`

Assuming `libncursesw` use, what is `n`? Is it (a) bytes count, (b) code-points (`wchar_t`) count, (c) graphemes (`cchar_t`) count, or (d) screen columns count?

(The (d) case is differ from (c) case if some `cchar_t` has unicode width > 1 and occupies multiply columns.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first off, it appears (6.2 ncurses source) that insnstr is defined as a macro calling winsnstr. winsnstr() is defined in ncurses/base/lib_insnstr.c. there, within USE_WIDEC_SUPPORT guards, ncurses performs an mbstowcs bound by n. that result is fed into wins_nwstr().

so it appears that n in this context bounds the number of bytes going into the mbstowcs(). mbstowcs() wants entire multibyte sequences (not interrupted ones). so in this context, n still would appear to mean byte count, and ought come on a multibyte boundary.

Comment: I was prompted, that mbstowcs takes wchar_t count! Thus, insnstr do the same. (I believe, it is very ugly API decision.)

Anyway, even this formally wrong answer have lead me to the success. But you can change it to make it even better when it was.